# Uniform continuity on an open interval implies boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I would like to show that if $f : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ is bounded. I have the following proof, which is probably relevant:

[image]

But, I cannot invoke the sequential compactness theorem, as that theorem states for two numbers $a$ and $b$, if $a < b$, then the interval $[a, b]$ is sequentially compact. I have been struggling with this problem for a while, and I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way than using that theorem. Suppose $f(x_n) \to \infty$ for some sequence $\{x_n\}$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers it has  a convergent subsequence, say $\{x_{n_k}\}$. Then $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is Cauchy sequence in $(a,b)$ , so $|f(x_{n_k})-f(x_{n_j})|\to 0$ as $j,k \to \infty$ (because of uniform continuity). This is a contradiction because any Cauchy sequence of real numbers is (convergent) hence bounded.

Comment: Hi, how do we know $\{x_{n}\}$ is bounded, and $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ is Cauchy in $(a, b)$?

Comment: @stackofhay42 $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $(a,b)$, thus, bounded and since, $(x_{n_k})$ is convergent, it's Cauchy.

Comment: can I just suppose there exists a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ such that the image sequence $\{f(x_{n})\}$ diverges, or would I need to prove such a sequence exists? can it be possible for no such sequence to exist?

Comment: If you suppose such a sequence exists and arrive at a contradiction then you can say that $f$ is necessarily bounded.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is a contradiction?

Comment: $f(x_{n_k})$ also tends to $\infty$ becasue $f(x_n) \to \infty$. But $(f(x_{n_k}))$ has been shown to be a Cauchy sequence. A Cauchy sequence cannot tend to $\infty$. @FD_bfa

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. @KaviRamaMurthy